# Push feature messes up my sorted insert feature C++

Tags: c++

I wrote a program to practice linked lists, and I am having an issue is with the Push and Sorted Insert feature.

Push works fine but whenever I push a number and then proceed with a sorted insert, it is almost never inserted correctly.

What is the issue?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
//Node Class
class Node
{
    public:
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

void printList(Node* node)
{
    cout<<endl;
    int i=0;
    while (node != NULL)
    {
        if(i==0)
        {
            cout<<node->data;
            node = node->next;
            i++;
        }
        else 
        {
            cout<<" "<<node->data;
            node = node->next;
        }
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
void push(Node** head_ref, int new_data)
{
    //Allocate node
    Node* new_node= new Node();
    //Insert data
    new_node->data=new_data;
    //Make "next node" of new node to the previous head
    new_node->next=(*head_ref);
    //move the head to point to the new node
    (*head_ref)=new_node;
}
void insertAfter(Node* prev_node, int new_data)
{
    if(prev_node==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"The given previous node cannot be NULL dummy pants.";
        return;
    }
    //Allocate new node
    Node* new_node= new Node();

    //insert data
    new_node->data=new_data;
    
    //Make the next of new node as the next of previous node
    new_node->next=prev_node->next;

    //Make the nexc of the previous node as new node
    prev_node->next=new_node;

}
void append(Node** head_ref, int new_data)
{
    //Allocate node
    Node* new_node= new Node();

    Node *last=*head_ref;
    
    //Insert data
    new_node->data=new_data;

    //Since the new node will be the last the "next" must be NULL
    new_node->next=NULL;

    //If the list is empty the new node will be the head.
    if(*head_ref==NULL)
    {
        *head_ref=new_node;
        return;
    }
    //traverse list until we are at the end
    while(last->next!=NULL)
    {
        last=last->next;
    }
    // change the next of the last node to the new last node
    last->next=new_node;
    return;
}
void sortedInsert(Node** head_ref, int new_data)
{
    Node* new_node=new Node();
    new_node->data=new_data;

    if(*head_ref==NULL||(*head_ref)->data>=new_node->data)
    {
        new_node->next=*head_ref;
        *head_ref=new_node;
        return;
    }

    Node* current = *head_ref;
    while(current->next!=NULL && current->data<new_node->data)
    {
        current=current->next;
    }

    new_node->next=current->next;
    current->next=new_node;

}
void deleteNode(Node** head_ref, int key)
{
    Node* temp= *head_ref;
    Node* prev= NULL;

    //If head node holds desired key, change the head and free the old head.
    if(temp!=NULL&&temp->data==key)
    {
        *head_ref=temp->next;
        delete temp;
        return;
    }
    //search for the key to be deleted. Keep track of previous node as we need to change 'prev->next'
    else{
    while(temp!=NULL&&temp->data!=key)
    {
        prev=temp;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    //if key is not found
    if(temp==NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    prev->next=temp->next;
    delete temp;
}
}
void deleteList(Node**head_ref)
{
    Node* current=*head_ref;
    Node* next= NULL;

    while(current!=NULL)
    {
        next=current->next;
        free(current);
        current=next;
    }
    *head_ref=NULL;
}

int main()
{
    //create a list with three nodes
    Node* head = NULL;
    Node* sorted = NULL;
   

    //allocate 3 nodes to the heap
    head = new Node();
    sorted = new Node();

    //assign data to desired input
    //link node to next node
    cout<<endl<<"--Welcome to linked list thingy--"<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter an integer to begin the linked list: "<<endl;
    int start;
    cin>>start;

    head->data=start;
    head->next=NULL;

    cout<<"Thank you\n";

    char choice;

    while (choice != 'Q'||choice !='Q')
    {
        cout<<"--Please choose from the selections bellow--"<<endl;
        cout<<"Press U to push an integer to front of list"<<endl;
        cout<<"Press A to append an integer to end of list"<<endl;
        cout<<"Press S to sort insert an integer to the list"<<endl;
        cout<<"Press D to delete an integer from the list"<<endl;
        cout<<"Press L to delete the entire list"<<endl;
        cout<<"Press Q to quit program"<<endl;
        cout<<"--------------------------------------------"<<endl;
        cout<<"Your choice: ";
        cin>>choice;
        cout<<endl;

    
        if(choice == 'U'||choice=='u')
        {
            int pushi;
            cout<<"Enter integer to push: ";
            cin>>pushi;
            push(&head,pushi);
            printList(head);
        }
        else if(choice=='A'||choice=='a')
        {
            int appendi;
            cout<<"Enter integer to append: ";
            cin>>appendi;
            append(&head, appendi);
            printList(head);
        }
        else if(choice=='S'||choice=='s')
        {
            int sorti;
            cout<<"Enter integer to sort insert: ";
            cin>>sorti;
            sortedInsert(&head,sorti);
            printList(head);
        }
        else if (choice=='D'||choice =='d')
        {
            int deleti;
            cout<<"Enter integer to delete: ";
            cin>>deleti;
            deleteNode(&head, deleti);
            printList(head);
        }
        else if(choice=='L'||choice=='l')
        {
            deleteList(&head);
            printList(head);
        }
        else if(choice=='Q'||choice=='q')
        {
            cout<<endl<<"---------"<<endl<<"Good bye!!"<<endl<<"---------"<<endl;
            sleep(3);
            break;
            
        }
        else
        {
            int random;
            srand(time(NULL));
            random=rand()%10+1;
     
            if(random%2==0)
            {
                cout<<"Are you blind?!? Pick one of the options, dummy."<<endl<<endl;
            }
            else if(random==9||random==7)
            {
                cout<<"Should we do any eye exam instead?"<<endl<<endl;
            }
            else if(random==3||random==5||random==1)
            {
                cout<<"Your reading is getting a lot better. Try again >:("<<endl<<endl;
            }

        }
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If you push a value into an unsorted list, where should the item go? Before the first item it finds that is larger than it? Should it sort the list and then insert into the sorted list?

Comment: Side note: `new` pairs with `delete` and it looks like the code calls `free` at one point instead.

Comment: Don't mix sorted and unsorted insertions. Split that into two classes.